# passing html element contents to another view

Tags: html, laravel

This has me stumped. What I think is a very simple task seems overly complicated to me. I have a start page with text element that contains a three letter code. I need to pass this code to the next page which uses the element as a query filter. This code is obtained initially via an API call, so I cannot obtain it from the database. I've been sifting through websites and the laravel documentation but am unable to find an answer to what would be a trivial task with the DOM. How do I pass this information to the next page? The laravel documentation is certainly not geared for a new user.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "session". https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz, I'll check that out now.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices. The first is using sessions, the second uses a query parameter. I will preface by saying you should be handling this stuff in controllers, especially sessions.

Method 1: Sessions.

You can 'flash' something to a session using this syntax:

`session()->flash('code', '12345')`

Keep in mind a flashed session will only last for 1 request and then be dumped. If you need it to last 2 sessions you can use `reflash()` to give you an extra session.

Now, in view 2 you can check for that session like so:

```
    @if ( session()->has('code') )
    {{ session()->get('code) }}
    @endif
```

Bare in mind, this is bad practice to be setting this stuff in views. This should be set in a controller, ideally. But you *can* do it.

Method 2: Query parameters

This is a *little* bit better for use in views, strictly, but still not ideal. In `view-1` you have a link to `view-2` like so:

`<a href="{{ route('view-2') }}?code=12345">Next page</a>`

Now in `view-2` you can grab it with this:

```
    <p>
    {{ Request::get('code') }}
    </p>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have a question though, how do you add an elements content into a session? For example:

Comment: Sorry, hit enter by mistake. For example:
<input type="text" value="" name="" size="4" maxlength="4" id="nick"><br><br>

Comment: The value in the "nick" is simply "ABC"

Comment: If you're using forms to set content and progress to the next page, I *strongly* urge you to set that stuff in a controller. So that I can better answer your question, can you provide more of your code and what you're trying to do? I could use that to formulate a more complete response with best practice support. Even just a simple explanation of the pages you have and what you're trying to accomplish would help.

Comment: Sorry, I was actually trying to read an element in the DOM which I now realize is pretty much impossible without all kinds of workarounds . I will reconstruct the app to make an API call to obtain the information. Thanks for your help. It is truly appreciated.